# Is there any python wrapper to submit my single job to High Performance Cluster managed by SGE?

Tags: python-3.x, hpc, sungridengine

I have already called multiprocessing package and used up all the CPUs in one node. I would like to use another 10 nodes to complete my job. Thus, I need 10 * 10 task threads to calculate it.  Is there some example code? I found this post ["How to use multiple nodes/cores on a cluster with parellelized Python code"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28072164/how-to-use-multiple-nodes-cores-on-a-cluster-with-parellelized-python-code)
. But I am still in confusion. For instance, the implemented interface,

```
job_task = perform_job(job_params, nodes, cups)
```

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.